# How do I get progress of this string using preg_match

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the progress from the string below but I can't do it.

I tried this code but no luck

```
preg_match("/[download] (.*?) of/", $content, $matches);

$content = '[youtube] PIh2xe4jnpk: Downloading webpage
[youtube] PIh2xe4jnpk: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Destination: MAGIC! - Rude (Official Music Video)-PIh2xe4jnpk.mp4
[download] 100% of 16.00MiB in 00:00';
```

I expect be 100 as an output

Comment: [ and ] have special meaning in regex. you have to escape it.

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: @Nawed Khan can you show me how? btw I'm not good in php

Comment: @miken32 when I `echo $matches[1];` its nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the [ and ] because they have special meaning in regex:

```
preg_match("/\[download\] (.*?) of/", $content, $matches);
```